# How does this Color marker happen in eclipse IDE ,and what should I do to clear the Color marker

Tags: eclipse

If I change the code the color will disappear, I do not know how does this happen.and when do we will use this features.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is? What is "this color marker"?

Comment: This looks like you did _Coverage_ instead of doing a normal _Run_. In the _Coverage_ view you can _Remove Active Session_ button to get rid of the background color. See also https://www.eclemma.org/

Comment: thanks！you are right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you **accidentally pressed the *Coverage* button instead of the *Run* or *Debug* button** next to it.

To remove the red background color do the following: in the *Coverage* view click the *Remove Active Session* or *Remove All Sessions* button.

For information on what this *Coverage* does and what it is used for, see the [EclEmma web site](https://www.eclemma.org/).

Answer (score 2):

This is activated because of code coverage. If you want to remove it then follow these steps.

1. Go to "Windows -> Show View -> Coverage" Select it. Click on "Open".
2. Open the "Coverage" view.
3. There are "X" and "XX" signs at upper right side.
4. Click on one of them as per your requirement to remove the coverage session.

Refer the screenshot for more details.

[image]