# How to change Eclipse Display Settings?

Tags: java, eclipse, settings, display

[image]

For all the time I open classes that I have, the pinkish blocks have been dragged. I want to clear these up but I have no idea what to do. (I'm using Eclipse Java Oxygen and Color Theme)

Comment: This is the Code Coverage tool. You should have a tab "Coverage" on the bottom panel, you can click on it and then click the grey X on the right and the highlighting should disappear.

Comment: Thank Ben, I solved this problem!

Comment: For details and what caused this, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49797857/6505250