# Why is Eclipse highlighting my code in red and how do I turn it off?

Tags: eclipse

Why is Eclipse highlighting my code in red and how do I turn it off?

[image]

Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)

Comment: What does the Annotations preference page show as using that background color? The Java editor's Syntax Coloring preference page?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798671/6505250

Answer (score 62):

This is activated because of code coverage. If you want to remove it then follow these steps.

1. Go to "Windows -> Show View -> Coverage" Select it. Click on "Open".
2. Open the "Coverage" view.
3. There are "X" and "XX" signs at upper right side. The "X" sign for
   remove single active session and "XX" for to remove all active
   sessions.
4. Click on one of them as per your requirement to remove the coverage
   session.

Refer the screenshot for more details.

[image]

Comment: "Show View > Coverage" doesn't exist in my Eclipse version (2020-06 Enterprise). I had to do "Show View > Other", then search for "Coverage" (it's in the "Java" section).

Answer (score 3):

Right click on project folder and then select on coverage configuration from configuration and deselect the source folder from configurations.
Hope this will help you.