# "All 2 branches missing" Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently set up a new workspace on Eclipse, and after importing my class files I ran into a strange error. It appears most of the code is highlighted red with the message "All 2 branches missing".

I have never run into this before, does anyone know what could be causing this and how I can avoid it in the future.

[image: What it looks like on my end]

Comment: It looks like the code coverage view. maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242665/why-is-eclipse-highlighting-my-code-in-red-and-how-do-i-turn-it-off?noredirect=1&lq=1?

Comment: TYVM this solved it

Comment: You're welcome :)