# Eclipse automatically turned on Git highlighting. How to turn it off?

Tags: java, git, eclipse

After I pushed my project the last time, Eclipse has started to permanently highlight most of my code in red (see screenshot). The highlighting goes away once I make any change but reappears every time I open a class. I just cannot figure out what setting leads to this highlighting, and it is extremely annoying.

The red diamond markers state "All 2 branches are missing". I am not using Git within Eclipse but in the console. Any help removing this behaviour would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Unwanted Git highlighting]

Comment: Sounds like you've left Code Coverage results showing.

Comment: Here the term _branch_ is not related to Git, but to code coverag (see [here](https://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/annotations.html)): https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798671/6505250

Comment: Oh, ok no wonder I could not find anything related to Git. Thank you so much!